# strrpos php function fails to work

Tags: php, string

I have got this function:

```
 function adjust_url_with_www_extract($host)
    {
       $pos =strrpos($host,"www.");
        if(  $pos === true  )
        {
          $host= substr($host,5);
        }

        return $host;
    }
```

I am calling it from this function:

```
  private function _unitTest()
    {
        $url="www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php";
        $result= $this->UnitTest->adjust_url_with_www_extract($url);
        return $result;
    }
```

But it never removes the www.. ause it never reaches the if condition..Why is that?

Comment: what's the expected output? based on the name of the function pretty much everything is wrong in that code.

Comment: I want to extract www. and return the url without it... not the best function name , I know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply do:

```
function adjust_url_with_www_extract( $host ) {
     return preg_replace( '~^www\.~', '', $host );
}
```

Comment: `str_replace` would be my choice. As far as I know it's considered bad practice to use the very resource hungry `preg_*` functions, when a simpler function works as well

Comment: @cypherabe I would agree with you, although I can imagine you only want to replace the "www." in the *beginning* of a URL. Imagine having a url like `www.yourwebsite.com/how-to-start-a-blogpost-on-the-www.html`? `str_replace` would render the URL invalid, preg_replace won't. Besides, preg_replace isn't *that* resource-hungry, even though str_replace is faster.

Answer (score 1):

The strrpos() function finds the position of the last occurrence of a string inside another string. This function returns the position on success, otherwise it returns FALSE. never return TRUE

so

strrpos($host,"www.") will give 0 for your url so 0 means false
add 1 to strrpos($host,"www.")+1 like this it will work

other wise strrpos($host,"www.") > -1 check like this

Comment: use this condition strrpos($host,"www.") > -1 in if

Comment: The strrpos() function finds the position of the last occurrence of a string inside another string.

This function returns the position on success, otherwise it returns FALSE.  never return TRUE

Comment: is it a funciton like indexOf that returns -1..if it finds nothing

Comment: won't work if there's no "www."  note: did you accept it because he said so? :D

Answer (score 1):

let's go line by line:

```
$pos =strrpos($host,"www.");
```

find the position of "www." (from reverse direction, huh?).

```
if(  $pos === false  )
```

if we didn't find it (huh?), strip the first 5(huh?) characters, return the rest:

```
    $host= substr($host,5);
```

otherwise return the whole host:

```
return $host;
```

So why do you expect it should work?

Comment: strrpos never returns `true`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php  note: please don't change the original question, the new code is just as bad...